# Customize content in Share using Swift

Tags: swift, share

I am trying to make a share button for my game. You know, the ones that when you click is a popup menu comes up with your options. I was wondering how I could make different options say different things. I was also wondering how I could make a "Save to Camera Roll" option. Ill post my code below.

```
@IBAction func share(sender: UIButton) {

    let firstActivity = "Yes! I scored \(ScoreNumber) in Dotcha! #dotcha @Snowcapps_Dev https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dotcha!/id977870313?ls=1&mt=8" 

    let activityViewController : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [firstActivity], applicationActivities: il)        
    self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)        
}
```

Comment: Do you have seen the Share Extensions introduced in iOS8 ? It could help you

Answer (score 5):

If you want to customize the text for Twitter, Facebook, Mail, etc, the you can inherit from the class [`UIActivityItemProvider`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityItemProvider_Class/index.html) in the following way :

```
class CustomProvider : UIActivityItemProvider {

    var facebookMessage: String!
    var twitterMessage: String!
    var emailMessage: String!

    init(placeholderItem: AnyObject, facebookMessage: String, twitterMessage: String, emailMessage: String) {
        super.init(placeholderItem: placeholderItem)
        self.facebookMessage = facebookMessage
        self.twitterMessage = twitterMessage
        self.emailMessage = emailMessage
    }

    override var item: Any {

        switch self.activityType! {
        case .postToFacebook:
            return self.facebookMessage!
        case .postToTwitter:
            return self.twitterMessage!
        case .mail:
            return self.emailMessage!
        default:
            return "Any Message"
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can call `UIActivityViewController` in the following way for example:

```
let firstActivityItem = CustomProvider(placeholderItem: "Default", facebookMessage: "Facebook", twitterMessage: "Twitter", emailMessage: "Mail")
let secondActivityItem = URL(string: "http://www.google.com")!
let image = UIImage(named: "nameofYOurImage.ext")!

let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
        activityItems: [firstActivityItem, secondActivityItem, image], applicationActivities: nil)    

self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In the `CustomProvider` class I only set Facebook, Twitter and Mail but you can put more if you want, it's up to you.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I read this but it doesn't really help me with the code part. I am trying to create different text for Email, Twitter and Facebook. I am also doing it in swift.

Comment: @CallumBondy See updated answer, but you should need to ask exactly what you want to do, before you comment your question is too broad to know exactly what's what you want.